# Cannot raise Max number of concurrent openvpn clients

Tags: openvpn

For same strange reason the number of concurrent clients that can connect to my openvpn server is limited to 70. No matter what parameter I change in server.conf the limit does not change. If I try to connect the 71st client errors like

> openvpn needs a gateway parameter

or

> dev tun also requires ifconfig

show up. If I restart openvpn server than the 71st client connects without errors.

There are a lot of UNDEF entries in my openvpn-status.log.

Here is my server.conf:

```
port 42000
proto udp
dev tun
ca /etc/openvpn/certs/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/certs/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/certs/server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh /etc/openvpn/certs/dh1024.pem
server 10.9.0.0 255.255.0.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
max-clients 300
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/staticclients
client-to-client
route 10.9.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.9.0.1
```

and my typical client.conf:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote host.domain.com 42000
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client-pc.crt
key client-pc.key
remote-cert-tls server
verb 3
```

Am I missing something?